# How to show link or action column in Kendo Grid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Kendo Grid and I want link when click columns. I want field: **"Name"**
link.and set css for link **Name**

This my code :

```
columns: [
   { field: "Id", title: " id", template: "<a href='http://www.codeproject.com/'>Id</a>" },
   { field: "Name", title: "Product Name" },
   {
     title: "Action",
     template: "<a href='http://www.codeproject.com/'>Edit</a>"
   },
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you have to set a [template](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-columns.template) to your column:

```
{ 
    field: "Name", 
    title: "Product Name",
    template: "<a href=''>#= Name #</a>"
},
```

And the styles you can apply by adding a class to the `a` tag.

Update:

To use `@Html.ActionLink` I suggest to use this kind of template:

```
<script id="link-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # var link = "@Html.ActionLink("{0}", "Index", "Home")".replace("{0}", Name); #
    #= link #
</script>
```

Then use as follow:

```
template: kendo.template($("#link-template").html())
```

Give it a try, I didn't tested it.

Comment: thanks how set templete with this sample   @Html.ActionLink("<#=Name #>", "Index", "Home"), when use see error  
SyntaxError: expected expression, got '<'
 

<a href="/">&lt;#=Name #&gt;</a>,

Comment: @saeed I updated the answer yesterday. Did you see it? I'm sorry for not letting you know.